# Tab Bootstrap : How to include a dynamic field

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my code I have for example 4 boostrap tab.
In the 2nd tab I want to create a new fields : eg : field33

How to insert a dynamic code in php inside the tab selected by a module called.

Do you know something can do that. I write a files (inside the datas for tab2) and the tab2 display the datas of file (field33).

Tk

```
 <div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist"  id="myTab">
        <li class="nav-item"><?php echo '<a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active">' .  TAB_GENERAL . '</a>'; ?></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><?php echo '<a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">' .  TAB_DESC . '</a>'; ?></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><?php echo '<a href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">' .  TAB_REF . '</a>'; ?></a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><?php echo '<a href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">' .  TAB_IMG . '</a>'; ?></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <div class="tab-content">
         <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            fields1
            fields2
         </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            fields3
            fields4
         </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            fields5
            fields6
         </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            fields6
            fields7
         </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: huh? are you asking to create something in the php file after it has rendered? or add something on the client-side?

Comment: In my idea, I activate a modules (it's little files) and in this modules tell to main files where the datas must be displayed. For example, the modules has a fields for tab3 and this field must be displayed in tab3.

Comment: Sorry i am not understanding what you are trying to do. Try asking a different way

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use [Jquery, Ajax and JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)